# JavaScript Object Structure Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects, for-in-loop

I am having an issue traversing the objects returned from uploaded file data, but it appears that potentially the object structure that is being returned is preventing me from capturing specific properties from each of the objects in the response or that I am misinterpreting how I should be accessing this object. When I log `data.length` I get 995, which I assume is the number of characters in the object response. When I log `data[prop]` It logs each individual character.

**Here is my returned file object data:**

```
[
  {
    "fieldname": "fileUpload",
    "originalname": "Screen Shot 2017-01-08 at 12.23.39 PM.png",
    "encoding": "7bit",
    "mimetype": "image/png",
    "size": 39881,
    "bucket": "test",
    "key": "1/2017-01-23/screen-shot-2017-01-08-at-12.23.39-pm.png",
    "acl": "public-read",
    "contentType": "image/png",
    "contentDisposition": null,
    "storageClass": "STANDARD",
    "metadata": null,
    "location": "https://test.s3.amazonaws.com/1/2017-01-23/screen-shot-2017-01-08-at-12.23.39-pm.png",
    "etag": "\"sfasgltg702o\""
  },
  {
    "fieldname": "fileUpload",
    "originalname": "Screen Shot 2017-01-08 at 12.21.04 PM.png",
    "encoding": "7bit",
    "mimetype": "image/png",
    "size": 58386,
    "bucket": "test",
    "key": "1/2017-01-23/screen-shot-2017-01-08-at-12.21.04-pm.png",
    "acl": "public-read",
    "contentType": "image/png",
    "contentDisposition": null,
    "storageClass": "STANDARD",
    "metadata": null,
    "location": "https://test.s3.amazonaws.com/1/2017-01-23/screen-shot-2017-01-08-at-12.21.04-pm.png",
    "etag": "\"151353j53j51u5j135ju\""
  }
]
```

**jQuery AJAX POST request uploading the files and returning the objects to `data`:**

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/app/sign',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function(data){
                console.log('upload successful! ' + data);

                console.log('Just the key ' + data.length);
                for(var prop in data){
                    console.log(data[prop]);
                }
            },
            error: function(error){
                console.log('error ' + JSON.stringify(error));
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data` is a JSON string, you have to parse it back to an array of objects using `JSON.parse` like this:

```
success: function(data){
    var arr = JSON.parse(data);

    // use arr as array
    console.log(arr.length);
    // arr[0] is the first object
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's just a **string** in JSON format. You need either `JSON.parse` to convert to a JS object, or use `$.getJSON()`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to access the first `fieldname`, you can access it this way `data[0].fieldname`. The same goes for the second: `data[1].fieldname`. Why ? because your data is interpreted like this:

```
0: {"fieldname": "fileUpload", ...}, 1: {"fieldname": "fileUpload", ...}
```